# Extremization of a Quartic Trigonometric Polynomial

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

Given positive integers $m,n$, define
$$P_{m,n}(\theta):= \left( \sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2 \sin^2( \theta-\alpha_i) \right) \left( \sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2 \sin^2( \theta-\beta_j) \right),$$

where $\{a_i\}, \{\alpha_i\}, \{b_j\} ,\{\beta_j\}$ are real numbers. I'm interested in the critical points of this function.

**My attempt:**

I managed to solve the $m=n=1$ case in closed form.
The minima occur at
$$ \theta \equiv \alpha_1 \pmod{\pi}, \\
   \theta \equiv \beta_1 \pmod{\pi} .$$

The maxima occur at
$$\theta \equiv \frac{\alpha_1+\beta_1}{2} \pmod{\frac{\pi}{2} }. $$

However, I couldn't solve in closed form any other general case (i.e. $m>1$ or $n>1$).

The derivative is in general
$$P_{m,n}'(\theta)=\left( \sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2 \sin( 2(\theta-\alpha_i)) \right) \left( \sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2 \sin^2( \theta-\beta_j) \right)+\left( \sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2 \sin^2( \theta-\alpha_i) \right) \left( \sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2 \sin( 2(\theta-\beta_j)) \right),$$

but I can't see how to get its roots.

**My questions:**

1. Can the critical points of $P_{m,n}$ be found in closed form?
2. If several minima/maxima exist, do they have the same minimum/maximum value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all rewrite the objective function as

$$P_{m,n}(\theta)=A_0+A_2 \cos 2\theta + A_4 \cos 4\theta +B_2 \sin 2\theta+B_4 \sin 4\theta ,$$
where the coefficients are given as bilinear forms
\begin{align}A_0 &= \phantom{+}\frac{1}{8} \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_i^2 b_j^2 \left(2+\cos (2\alpha_i -2\beta_j) \right),\\
A_2&= -\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_i^2 b_j^2 \left( \cos (2\alpha_i) + \cos (2\beta_j) \right),\\
A_4&= \phantom{+}\frac{1}{8}\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_i^2 b_j^2 \left( \cos \left(2\alpha_i + 2\beta_j \right) \right), \\
B_2&= -\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_i^2 b_j^2 \left( \sin (2\alpha_i) + \sin( 2\beta_j) \right),\\
B_4&= \phantom{+}\frac{1}{8}\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_i^2 b_j^2 \left( \sin \left(2\alpha_i + 2\beta_j \right) \right). 
\end{align}

Upon differentiation, we get

$$P_{m,n}'(\theta)=2 B_2 \cos 2 \theta +4 B_4 \cos 4 \theta - 2A_2 \sin 2 \theta - 4A_4 \sin 4\theta. $$

Use the substitution
$$z=\mathrm{e}^{i \theta} \leftrightarrow \theta = \arg z $$ to characterize critical points using roots of

$$2B_2 \frac{z^2+z^{-2}}{2}+4B_4 \frac{z^4+z^{-4}}{2}-2A_2 \frac{z^2-z^{-2}}{2i}-4A_4 \frac{z^4-z^{-4}}{2i}. $$

The equation is equivalent to the octic polynomial
$$2 (-i A_4 + B_4) + (-i A_2 + B_2) z^2 + (i A_2 + B_2) z^6 + 
 2 (i A_4 + B_4) z^8=0. $$

Note that the substitution $w=z^2$ allows for a solution involving the quartic formula.